# How do I use Mullvad's post-quantum safe tunnels with another WireGuard VPN client?

Tags: vpn, security, wireguard

Mullvad includes setup instructions on their website for using their service with WireGuard clients on different platforms. Is it possible to use their [quantum-resistant tunnel feature](https://mullvad.net/en/blog/2022/11/8/post-quantum-safe-vpn-tunnels-available-on-all-wireguard-servers) in a WireGuard config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using WireGuard’s pre-shared key (PSK) option and Mullvad’s [`psk-exchange` utility](https://github.com/mullvad/mullvadvpn-app/blob/main/talpid-tunnel-config-client/examples/psk-exchange.rs). Instructions to setup:

**Note:** Requires [`git`](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and a working [Rust installation](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install).

1. Generate a WireGuard configuration and connect to it by following the instructions on Mullvad's website.

   - [Linux](https://mullvad.net/en/help/easy-wireguard-mullvad-setup-linux)
   - [macOS](https://mullvad.net/en/help/wireguard-macos-app)
   - [Windows](https://mullvad.net/en/help/wireguard-app-windows)
2. Clone the [`mullvadvpn-app` repo](https://github.com/mullvad/mullvadvpn-app) and build the `psk-exchange` utility.

```sh
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/mullvad/mullvadvpn-app.git
cd mullvadvpn-app/talpid-tunnel-config-client
cargo build --example psk-exchange
```

3. Ensure the VPN is connected via the downloaded WireGuard config before continuing, or the default Mullvad client **with the quantum-resistant tunnel turned off**. Then run:

```
cargo run --example psk-exchange "10.64.0.1" PUBLIC_KEY
```

where `PUBLIC_KEY` is the `WIREGUARD KEY`  shown under [`Manage WireGuard keys`](https://mullvad.net/en/account/wireguard-config) on Mullvad's website for the profile you just created. It can also be displayed via:

```sh
grep -m1 "PrivateKey = " ./xx-xxx-wg-xxx.conf  | cut -c14- | wg pubkey
```

After running `psk-exchange`, you should see output like the following:

```
private key: PRIVATE_KEY
psk: PRESHARED_KEY
```

4. Copy a WireGuard config file to amend with a `PresharedKey`.

   ```
   # Note that the max length of a Linux interface name is 15 characters.
   cp /path/to/xx-xxx-wg-xxx.conf /path/to/xx-xxx-wgq-xxx.conf
   ```
5. Edit the copied file and add `PresharedKey = KEY` under `[Peer]`, and update `PrivateKey` to match the value shown above. Example file shown [on this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/WireGuard#wg-quick) under `Peer A setup`.
6. Use updated config with WireGuard client and confirm it connects.

You can also use a script like the following to generate a config quickly:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -o errexit -o nounset

MULLVAD_REPO="/path/to/mullvadvpn-app"
SCRIPT_NAME="$(basename "$0")"

main() (
    if [ $# != 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME <public_key> <config>" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    public_key="$1"
    config="$(realpath "$2")"
    config_dir="$(dirname "$config")"
    config_basename="$(basename "$config" .conf)"
    cd "$MULLVAD_REPO/talpid-tunnel-config-client"
    echo "Generating PSK for $config_basename.conf..."
    {
        read -r private_key
        read -r preshared_key
    } <<EOF
$(cargo run --example psk-exchange "10.64.0.1" "$public_key")
EOF
    private_key="$(echo "$private_key" | cut -c14-)"
    preshared_key="$(echo "$preshared_key" | cut -c6-)"
    updated_config_basename="$(echo "$config_basename" | sed "s/-wg-/-wgq-/g")"

    sed "s:PrivateKey = [^[:space:]]*:PrivateKey = $private_key:;s:\[Peer\]:&\nPresharedKey = $preshared_key:" \
        "$config" >"$config_dir/$updated_config_basename.conf"
    echo "Wrote config $updated_config_basename.conf"
)

main "$@"
```

Initially I looked into this to improve desktop performance, since Mullvad uses an Electron frontend. But it turns out Mullvad also has a [dedicated CLI](https://mullvad.net/en/help/how-use-mullvad-cli) which works even when the GUI is closed, so now I'm preferring that instead. However, the WireGuard config is still useful for running [Mullvad on a router](https://mullvad.net/en/help/running-wireguard-router) and on systems that don't support their client.

Mullvad's quantum-resistant encryption spec is documented [here](https://github.com/mullvad/mullvadvpn-app/blob/main/talpid-tunnel-config-client/proto/tunnel_config.proto).